# TailwindCC: no-underline class does not work for my <a> tag?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to avoid having underlines under my `<a>` tags. I have added the class `"no-underline"` as per the docs but I'm still getting the underlines under my links? I have added the code im using below:

```
<div
  class="
    my-3
    flex flex-wrap
    -m-1
    text-center
    justify-center
    items-center
    no-underline
  "
>
  <div class="m-auto">
    {% for tag in tags %}
    <a
      href="{% routablepageurl blog_page 'post_by_tag' tag.slug %}"
      class="no-underline"
    >
      <span
        class="
          font-mono
          m-1
          bg-gray-200
          hover:bg-gray-300
          rounded-full
          px-2
          py-1
          font-bold
          text-sm
          leading-loose
          cursor-pointer
          shadow-lg
          no-underline
        "
        >{{ tag }}</span
      >
    </a>
    {% empty %} No tags yet {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>

Thanks for the help!
```

Comment: What is the stylesheet for that class? Typically it's `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: Another observation is your class has so many classes and `hover:bg-gray-300` this isn't a class

Comment: @Bharat, I am using tailwindCSS, the classes you mentioned are built-in with the naming convention that I am using.

Comment: Ahh I get it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `no-underline` in to

```
<div class="m-auto">
```

And make sure that there are no `underline` class in the parent divs.

You can also try to add

```
style="text-decoration: none !important;"
```

into the divs tag if those doesn't work.

Comment: I added `style="text-decoration: none !important;"` to my a tag, thanks for helping me out here.